# what is the mechanism of configuring Spring Cloud Config in a bootstrap.properties file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

According to the docs, to connect to the config server, `spring.application.name` and `spring.cloud.config.uri` should be set in a `bootstrap.properties` file for the config client, such that the parameters fetched from the config server can be prior to those set locally. I am just wondering how this works, since:

1. I searched the source code of Spring Cloud Config Client, but cannot find what it does with the `bootstrap.properties`
2. It still works if I set `spring.application.name` in `application.properties`

Is it a feature of SpringBoot?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not located in spring-cloud-config. Instead, it is in spring-cloud-context which is a dependency of spring-cloud-config.

Basically, it creates a parent context for the actual context of the application and initializes it with the parameters of the bootstrap.

You can find more information in https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature of spring cloud. The `spring.cloud.config.uri` needs to be set in `bootstratp.properties`. This comes from the spring-cloud-commons project. My guess is you might be running the config server in the default location of `localhost:8888`.